# Some errors which are from Spring Servlet are not being logged in log files but showing on console

Tags: spring, servlets, logback

[image]

I have attached the error logs that are being showing on console. But it is not showing on log files. I am using rolling file appender within logback.xml.

```
Jun 14, 2023 6:57:28 PM 
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest getEntity
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class 
com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, and Java type class 
com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, and MIME media type 
text/plain; charset=UTF-8 was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME 
media type are:
text/plain; charset=UTF-8 ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
```

It would be highly appreciated if anyone can come forward to help with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add the output as text with code tags instead of an image (I cannot read it on my screen).

Comment: Those are from Jersey not from Spring. Judging from the output it uses java.util.logging instead of a logging framework, so it will not use/route to logback. You might need the SLF4J bridge for JUL.

Comment: @M.Deinum I added the bridge dependency, but it is still not working

Comment: @M.Deinum in my web.xml, I am using this servlet-class "com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet"

Comment: Which is Jersey and not Spring. It is a jersey provided classes to integrate Jersey with Spring. BUt as stated I have no clue on what logging framework/API that uses, also when using JUL how/when to register the bridge is tricky afaik.